# Transform paper folding diagram to 3D object or vice versa

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, 3d

I made this commands to make paper models, and I ask if it is possible to have a 3D view of them converting in tikz-3D, or backward. But it's easier to draw the flat model and generate the volume after. Calculations could be made with `lualatex`. If you have an idea to follow ?

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{%
    patron/.style={%
        line join=round,
        rounded corners=.05pt,
        draw, thin},
    patron side/.style={patron},
    patron languette/.style={patron},
    }

\newcounter{NodePat}

\NewDocumentCommand{\PolygReg}{%
    O{3}    % nb de cotés
    m       % segment A/B
    O{A}    % nom générique
    }{%
    \foreach \a/\b in {#2} {%
    \path[patron side] let
    \p1 = ($(\a)!.5!(\b)$) ,
    \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} ,
    \p2 = ($(\p1)!1/tan(180/#1)!90:(\b)$)
    in
    (\a)--(\b)
    \foreach \i [%
        evaluate=\i as \j using (\i-1)*360/#1] in {3,...,#1} {%
        -- ($(\p2)!1!\j:(\a)$) coordinate (#3\theNodePat)
            \pgfextra{\stepcounter{NodePat}}
        }
         -- cycle ;
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Languette}{%
    O{.15}  % largeur
    D<>{45} % angle sur le premier node
    m       % les deux nodes
    D<>{45} % angle sur le second node
    O{A}
    }{%
    \foreach \b/\a in {#3} {%
    \path[patron languette] let
    \p1 = ($(#5\b)!#1/sin(#2)!-#2:(#5\a)$),
    \p2 = ($(#5\a)!#1/sin(#4)!#4:(#5\b)$)
    in
    (#5\a) -- (#5\b)
         -- (\p1)
         -- (\p2)
         -- cycle ; }
}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AffNodesPatron}[1][A]{%
    \newcount\X
    \X=1
    \loop
    \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@pi@A\the\X\endcsname\pgfpictureid
        \node[font={\footnotesize},red] at (A\the\X) {A\the\X} ;
        \advance \X by 1
    \else
        \X=0
    \fi
    \unless\ifnum \X=0
    \repeat
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

\coordinate (A1) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (A2) at (1,0) ;
\setcounter{NodePat}{3}

\PolygReg[4]{A1/A2}
\PolygReg{A3/A2,A5/A2,A5/A6,A5/A7}

\Languette{1/2,5/3,3/4,4/1}

%\AffNodesPatron

\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A1) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (A2) at (1,0) ;
\setcounter{NodePat}{3}

\PolygReg[6]{A1/A2,A4/A3,A6/A5,A2/A1}
\PolygReg[4]{A17/A16}
\PolygReg[6]{A20/A19,A20/A24,A23/A22,A21/A19}
\PolygReg[4]{A5/A4,A3/A2,A1/A6,A24/A23,A22/A21}

\Languette<30>{3/7,7/8,8/9,9/10,10/4,37/38,5/11,11/12,12/13,13/14,14/6,41/42,%
    42/1,15/16,16/19,21/45,22/29,32/23,28/20,17/18,2/39,39/40}<30>

%\AffNodesPatron

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sounds complicated...I would start by representing the underlying structure as a more abstract Lua object so that it is immediate to tell whether a specific component is a "languette" or a face and how the faces are connected. Then from that representation you can produce both views, the flat and the 3D

Comment: @Bordaigorl This way its seems complicated. I thaught about rotating nodes around vertices as one does when one make the paper model : rotating node A5...A8 around A2-A3 by 120°, then A6...A8 around A2--A5 by ... One has just angles to calculate. Initially all nodes have 0 as z coordinate, then a lualatex macro makes the rotations. Is such a thing possible ? (at the end all languettes are gone).

Comment: @Bordaigorl The fact is that each rotation is defined by the axe and a node and its image, no need for angle calculation.

Comment: Did you see the `folding` library of TikZ by the way?

Comment: @percusse In the manual it is written that there is only one commande to make a dodecahedron. I missed something ?

Comment: Check TikZ version 3.0

Comment: @percusse Silly me, I use 2.10 documentation version... There is more shapes, but nothing concerning folding the models or am I wrong again ? ;-( Thank you. I have no time now, but I'll try my rotation idea, or a better one if one could help me.

Comment: @Tarass Is it possible to modify your fine code, so that text could be added inside specific faces. For example to add text (in figures which have lines to be cut) near the lines to be cut, which also could be made more thick. Thank you.

Comment: Yes feel free to use and modify the code as you wish. Nk.

Comment: @Tarass How can your code be modified (as I've asked you)? I have no programming ability. Thank you.