# Inserting text in a polyhedral folding drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, polygon

Using the following code from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213566/transform-paper-folding-diagram-to-3d-object-or-vice-versa),
is it possible to modify the code to insert text inside different faces?

Also is it possible to control the shape of the folding and cutting lines?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{folding,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
patron/.style={%
 line join=round, rounded corners=.05pt, draw, thin},
patron side/.style={patron},
patron languette/.style={patron},
}
\newcounter{NodePat}
\NewDocumentCommand{\PolygReg}{%
O{3}
m
O{A}
}
{%
\foreach \a/\b in {#2} 
{%
\path[patron side] let
\p1 = ($(\a)!.5!(\b)$) ,
\n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} ,
\p2 = ($(\p1)!1/tan(180/#1)!90:(\b)$)
in
(\a)--(\b)
\foreach \i [%
  evaluate=\i as \j using (\i-1)*360/#1] in {3,...,#1} {%
  -- ($(\p2)!1!\j:(\a)$) coordinate (#3\theNodePat)
  \pgfextra{\stepcounter{NodePat}}
  }
-- cycle ;}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Languette}{%
O{.15}
D<>{45}
m
D<>{45}
O{A}
}
{%
\foreach \b/\a in {#3} {%
\path[patron languette] let
\p1 = ($(#5\b)!#1/sin(#2)!-#2:(#5\a)$),
\p2 = ($(#5\a)!#1/sin(#4)!#4:(#5\b)$)
in
(#5\a) -- (#5\b) -- (\p1) -- (\p2) -- cycle ; }
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AffNodesPatron}[1][A]{%
 \newcount\X
 \X=1
 \loop
 \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@pi@A\the\X\endcsname\pgfpictureid
 \node[font={\footnotesize},red] at (A\the\X) {A\the\X} ;
 \advance \X by 1
 \else
 \X=0
 \fi
 \unless\ifnum \X=0
 \repeat
}
\makeatother
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (A2) at (0,-1) ;
\setcounter{NodePat}{3}
\PolygReg{A1/A2,A1/A3,A3/A2,A5/A2}
\Languette{3/4,6/5,2/6}
\AffNodesPatron
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "shape"? Color, line style, line width? If yes, modify the  `patron side` and `patron languette` styles, I suppose.

Comment: @– Torbjørn T. I use this code to draw different drawings in the same document, with different number of faces. This is defined in line \PolygReg[4]{} for a 4-faces drawing for example. In some drawings, some lines are bent the other way. I need to make these specific lines with different style in this specific drawing. For example, In my drawing, I need to make the line between vertex A1 and A3 dashed, instead of the default solid line. Can this be added in the code as a variable, to be altered in individual drawings? And I need to add text on this specific line saying (cut here).

Comment: OK. Probably possible, but I can't immediately see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you only need to put `\node`s where you need each text. For example, a code for your second figure could be the following:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,line join=round,line cap=round]
\foreach\xi in {1,2,3}
{%
  \begin{scope}[shift={(120*\xi-90:1)},rotate=120*\xi-180]
    \draw[green,dashed] (90:1)  -- (-30:1) -- (210:1);
    \draw[blue] (210:1) -- (90:1) -- (30:0.8) -- (-30:1);
  \end{scope}
}
\node[red,fill=yellow]    at   (0,0) {1};
\node[magenta,rotate=-60] at  (30:1) {2};
\node[green,rotate=60]    at (150:1) {\huge 4};
\node[green,rotate=180]   at (270:1) {\bfseries 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Now look at the last lines of the code. The line

```
\node[red,fill=yellow] at (0,0) {1};
```

will draw a node at the point `(0,0)` with the text `1` in red and with a yellow filling, and so on.

PS. I wrote a brief code for this drawing, but it will be the same in the code you posted. You only need to adjust the coordinates to the desired positions.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But I use the posted code to draw several drawings (with different number of faces) in the same document. So I need to modify the posted code, for example by adding variables, so that it could be applied to each drawing separately as needed. Unfortunately I do not know how to do that.