# Modifying a paper-folding-diagram code

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following modified code from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213566/transform-paper-folding-diagram-to-3d-object-or-vice-versa),
to draw a part of Truncated Icosahedron (in a still progressing project), in a document that contains other models; which produces the first drawing.

Is it possible to modify the code (used for this particular model, without affecting the default code which is used for other models in the document), so that the pentagons could be coloured red, and the languettes could be coloured yellow, as in the second
drawing!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
patron/.style={%
 line join=round, rounded corners=.05pt, draw, thin},
patron side/.style={patron},
patron languette/.style={patron},%
}
\newcounter{NodePat}
\NewDocumentCommand{\PolygReg}{%
O{3}    %
m       %
O{A}    %
}
{%
\foreach \a/\b in {#2} 
{%
\path[patron side] let
\p1 = ($(\a)!.5!(\b)$) ,
\n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} ,
\p2 = ($(\p1)!1/tan(180/#1)!90:(\b)$)
in
(\a)--(\b)
\foreach \i [%
  evaluate=\i as \j using (\i-1)*360/#1] in {3,...,#1} {%
  -- ($(\p2)!1!\j:(\a)$) coordinate (#3\theNodePat)
  \pgfextra{\stepcounter{NodePat}}
  }
-- cycle ;
}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Languette}{%
O{.15}  %
D<>{30} %
m       %
D<>{30} %
O{A}
}
{%
\foreach \b/\a in {#3} {%
\path[patron languette] let
\p1 = ($(#5\b)!#1/sin(#2)!-#2:(#5\a)$),
\p2 = ($(#5\a)!#1/sin(#4)!#4:(#5\b)$)
in
(#5\a) -- (#5\b) -- (\p1) -- (\p2) -- cycle ; }
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AffNodesPatron}[1][A]{%
 \newcount\X
 \X=1
 \loop
 \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@pi@A\the\X\endcsname\pgfpictureid
 \node[font={\footnotesize},red] at (A\the\X) {A\the\X} ;
 \advance \X by 1
 \else
 \X=0
 \fi
 \unless\ifnum \X=0
 \repeat
}
\makeatother
\hskip -1.8cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (A2) at (0,-1) ;
\setcounter{NodePat}{3}
\PolygReg[5]{A1/A2}
\PolygReg[6]{A2/A1,A1/A5,A5/A4,A4/A3,A3/A2}
\PolygReg[5]{A7/A6,A11/A10,A15/A14,A19/A18,A23/A22}
\Languette<12>{1/6,5/10,4/14,3/18,2/22,6/26,10/29,14/32,18/35,22/38}
\AffNodesPatron
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define either `\filltrue` to get the image below or `\fillfalse` to get the outlines only.  Since `\iffill` can be changed on the fly to either true or false, you can turn the flag true when you want the filled rendition, and then reset it false for all other renditions.

I first create a new if, `\newif\iffill`. Then at the beginning of the macro definition `\PolygReg`, I add this line:

```
\iffill\ifnum#1=5\def\tmp{fill=red}\else\def\tmp{}\fi\else\def\tmp{}\fi
```

This will define `\tmp` as `fill=red` only if `\filltrue` and `\ifnum#1=5` (i.e., pentagon), otherwise it will be set empty.  Then, when invoking the path, I use

```
\expandafter\path\expandafter[\tmp, patron side] let
```

so that `\tmp` gets expanded prior to execution of `\path`.

I do something comparable for the definition of `\Languette`, but with the golden color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newif\iffill
\filltrue
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
patron/.style={%
 line join=round, rounded corners=.05pt, draw, thin},
patron side/.style={patron},
patron languette/.style={patron},%
}
\newcounter{NodePat}
\NewDocumentCommand{\PolygReg}{%
O{3}    %
m       %
O{A}    %
}
{%
\iffill\ifnum#1=5\def\tmp{fill=red}\else\def\tmp{}\fi\else\def\tmp{}\fi
\foreach \a/\b in {#2} 
{%
\expandafter\path\expandafter[\tmp, patron side] let
\p1 = ($(\a)!.5!(\b)$) ,
\n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} ,
\p2 = ($(\p1)!1/tan(180/#1)!90:(\b)$)
in
(\a)--(\b)
\foreach \i [%
  evaluate=\i as \j using (\i-1)*360/#1] in {3,...,#1} {%
  -- ($(\p2)!1!\j:(\a)$) coordinate (#3\theNodePat)
  \pgfextra{\stepcounter{NodePat}}
  }
-- cycle ;
}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Languette}{%
O{.15}  %
D<>{30} %
m       %
D<>{30} %
O{A}
}
{%
\iffill\def\tmp{fill=yellow!70!orange}\else\def\tmp{}\fi
\foreach \b/\a in {#3} {%
\expandafter\path\expandafter[\tmp, patron languette] let
\p1 = ($(#5\b)!#1/sin(#2)!-#2:(#5\a)$),
\p2 = ($(#5\a)!#1/sin(#4)!#4:(#5\b)$)
in
(#5\a) -- (#5\b) -- (\p1) -- (\p2) -- cycle ; }
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AffNodesPatron}[1][A]{%
 \newcount\X
 \X=1
 \loop
 \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@pi@A\the\X\endcsname\pgfpictureid
 \node[font={\footnotesize},red] at (A\the\X) {A\the\X} ;
 \advance \X by 1
 \else
 \X=0
 \fi
 \unless\ifnum \X=0
 \repeat
}
\makeatother
\hskip -1.8cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (A2) at (0,-1) ;
\setcounter{NodePat}{3}
\PolygReg[5]{A1/A2}
\PolygReg[6]{A2/A1,A1/A5,A5/A4,A4/A3,A3/A2}
\PolygReg[5]{A7/A6,A11/A10,A15/A14,A19/A18,A23/A22}
\Languette<12>{1/6,5/10,4/14,3/18,2/22,6/26,10/29,14/32,18/35,22/38}
\AffNodesPatron
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

The OP asked via comment for more capability:

1. to have multiple default polygon colors defined and
2. To allow color override for individual n-gons.

The OP tried an attempt to address point 1, but missed an important detail.  If `#1` matches *none* of the prespecified n-gon defaults, one must nix the fill, or else the last known fill will be used.

For point 2, I added a second optional argument to `\PolygReg`, in which the actual `fill =` option may be specified.

Thus, the revised test is now

```
\ifx\relax#2\relax
  \iffill
    \ifnum#1=3 \def\tmp{fill=violet}\else
    \ifnum#1=4 \def\tmp{fill=blue}\else
    \ifnum#1=5 \def\tmp{fill=red}\else
    \def\tmp{}\fi\fi\fi
  \else
    \def\tmp{}%
  \fi 
\else
  \def\tmp{#2}
\fi
```

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newif\iffill
\filltrue
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
patron/.style={%
 line join=round, rounded corners=.05pt, draw, thin},
patron side/.style={patron},
patron languette/.style={patron},%
}
\newcounter{NodePat}
\NewDocumentCommand{\PolygReg}{%
O{3}    %
O{}
m       %
O{A}    %
}
{%
\ifx\relax#2\relax
  \iffill
    \ifnum#1=3 \def\tmp{fill=violet}\else
    \ifnum#1=4 \def\tmp{fill=blue}\else
    \ifnum#1=5 \def\tmp{fill=red}\else
    \def\tmp{}\fi\fi\fi
  \else
    \def\tmp{}%
  \fi 
\else
  \def\tmp{#2}
\fi
\foreach \a/\b in {#3} 
{%
\expandafter\path\expandafter[\tmp, patron side] let
\p1 = ($(\a)!.5!(\b)$) ,
\n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} ,
\p2 = ($(\p1)!1/tan(180/#1)!90:(\b)$)
in
(\a)--(\b)
\foreach \i [%
  evaluate=\i as \j using (\i-1)*360/#1] in {3,...,#1} {%
  -- ($(\p2)!1!\j:(\a)$) coordinate (#4\theNodePat)
  \pgfextra{\stepcounter{NodePat}}
  }
-- cycle ;
}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Languette}{%
O{.15}  %
D<>{30} %
m       %
D<>{30} %
O{A}
}
{%
\iffill\def\tmp{fill=yellow!70!orange}\else\def\tmp{}\fi
\foreach \b/\a in {#3} {%
\expandafter\path\expandafter[\tmp, patron languette] let
\p1 = ($(#5\b)!#1/sin(#2)!-#2:(#5\a)$),
\p2 = ($(#5\a)!#1/sin(#4)!#4:(#5\b)$)
in
(#5\a) -- (#5\b) -- (\p1) -- (\p2) -- cycle ; }
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AffNodesPatron}[1][A]{%
 \newcount\X
 \X=1
 \loop
 \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@pi@A\the\X\endcsname\pgfpictureid
 \node[font={\footnotesize},red] at (A\the\X) {A\the\X} ;
 \advance \X by 1
 \else
 \X=0
 \fi
 \unless\ifnum \X=0
 \repeat
}
\makeatother
\hskip -1.8cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (A2) at (0,-1) ;
\setcounter{NodePat}{3}
\PolygReg[5]{A1/A2}
\PolygReg[6]{A2/A1,A1/A5,A5/A4,A4/A3,A3/A2}
\PolygReg[5]{A7/A6,A11/A10,A15/A14,A19/A18}
\PolygReg[5][fill=cyan]{A23/A22}
\PolygReg[3]{A40/A39}
\Languette<12>{1/6,5/10,4/14,3/18,2/22,6/26,10/29,14/32,18/35,22/38}
\AffNodesPatron
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. To expand your code more, I modified it, to fill other polygons as \iffill
\ifnum#1=3\def\tmp{fill=violet}\fi\ifnum#1=4\def\tmp{fill=blue}\fi\ifnum#1=5\def\tmp{fill=red}\fi\ifnum#1=6\def\tmp{fill=green}\fi
\else\def\tmp{}\fi
But, as  you can see from https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVU3R.png I could not control other polygons. Is it possible to add a variable in your code, then define the colour in individual polygons as for example \PolygReg[5, red]{A1/A2}
    \PolygReg[6, green]{A2/A1,A1/A5,A5/A4,A4/A3,A3/A2}

Comment: @Hany Assume `\filltrue`.  Your code does not do anything for cases when `#1` is not a `3`, `4`, `5`, or `6`.  Thus, it retains the most recently used color when it hits an n-gon of a different index.  You need your `\ifnum` to cascade with the use of `\else` , so that the last `\else` clause covers the case when the number does not match any test case.  And that last `\else` clause must also `\def\tmp{}` (not only when `\fillfalse`).

Comment: @Hany Here: `\iffill \ifnum#1=3\relax\def\tmp{fill=violet}\else\ifnum#1=4 \def\tmp{fill=blue}\else\ifnum#1=5\relax\def\tmp{fill=red}\else\def\tmp{}\fi\fi\fi\else\def\tmp{}\fi `  Note that `\def\tmp{}` occurs twice: once when `\fillfalse`, and the other if `#1` matches none of the test cases.

Comment: @Hany Please see my **SUPPLEMENT**

Comment: @– Steven B. Segletes Thank you very very much for your answer, explanation, time, and concern.