# Drawing a paper-folding model

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the following modified code from the answer to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612523/modifying-a-paper-folding-diagram-code).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=10mm, right=10mm, top=10mm, bottom=10mm}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false,colorlinks,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue, plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,breaklinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{folding,calc,calendar,decorations,arrows,automata,positioning,mindmap,backgrounds}
\newif\iffill
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
patron/.style={%
 line join=round, rounded corners=.05pt, draw, thin},
patron side/.style={patron},
patron languette/.style={patron},%
}
\newcounter{NodePat}
\NewDocumentCommand{\PolygReg}{%
O{3}%
O{}
m%
O{A}%
}
{%
\ifx\relax#2\relax
  \iffill
    \ifnum#1=3 \def\tmp{fill=blue!25!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=4 \def\tmp{fill=blue!30!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=5 \def\tmp{fill=blue!35!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=6 \def\tmp{fill=blue!40!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=7 \def\tmp{fill=blue!45!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=8 \def\tmp{fill=blue!50!white}\else
    \def\tmp{}\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \else
    \def\tmp{}
  \fi 
\else
  \def\tmp{#2}
\fi


\foreach \a/\b in {#3} 
{%
\expandafter\path\expandafter[\tmp, patron side] let
\p1 = ($(\a)!.5!(\b)$) ,
\n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} ,
\p2 = ($(\p1)!1/tan(180/#1)!90:(\b)$)
in
(\a)--(\b)
\foreach \i [%
  evaluate=\i as \j using (\i-1)*360/#1] in {3,...,#1} {%
  -- ($(\p2)!1!\j:(\a)$) coordinate (#4\theNodePat)
  \pgfextra{\stepcounter{NodePat}}
  }
-- cycle ;
}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Languette}{%
O{.15}  %
D<>{24} %
m       %
D<>{24} %
O{A}
}%
{%
\foreach \b/\a in {#3} {%
\path[patron languette, fill=yellow] let
\p1 = ($(#5\b)!#1/sin(#2)!-#2:(#5\a)$),
\p2 = ($(#5\a)!#1/sin(#4)!#4:(#5\b)$)
in
(#5\a) -- (#5\b) -- (\p1) -- (\p2) -- cycle ; }
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AffNodesPatron}[1][A]{%
 \newcount\X
 \X=1
 \loop
 \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@pi@A\the\X\endcsname\pgfpictureid
 \node[font={\footnotesize},red] at (A\the\X) {A\the\X} ;
 \advance \X by 1
 \else
 \X=0
 \fi
 \unless\ifnum \X=0
 \repeat
}
\makeatother

\filltrue
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.2, rotate=0]
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (A2) at (0,-1) ;
\setcounter{NodePat}{3}
\PolygReg{A1/A2,A3/A2,A3/A4,A4/A2,A4/A6,A4/A7}
\PolygReg{A7/A6,A9/A6,A9/A10,A11/A10}
\PolygReg{A9/A11,A9/A13}
\PolygReg{A14/A13,A15/A13,A14/A15,A14/A17,A18/A17}
\PolygReg{A15/A16,A20/A16,A15/A20}
\PolygReg{A20/A21,A20/A23,A24/A23}
\Languette{5/3,2/6,10/12,19/18,13/16,16/21,21/23}
\AffNodesPatron
\draw [thick, white, dashed] (A3.center) -- (A5.center) (A5.center) -- (A6.center) (A2.center) -- (A13.center) (A6.center) -- (A7.center) (A10.center) -- (A12.center) (A18.center) -- (A19.center) (A18.center) -- (A13.center) (A13.center) -- (A22.center) (A13.center) -- (A21.center) (A21.center) -- (A23.center) (A21.center) -- (A22.center);
\draw [draw=none] (A1.center) -- (A2.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=.15cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf G};
\draw [draw=none] (A1.center) -- (A3.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.2cm] {\scriptsize\bf G};
\draw [draw=none] (A3.center) -- (A5.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=.18cm] {\scriptsize\bf H};
\draw [draw=none] (A2.center) -- (A6.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=-.18cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf A};
\draw [draw=none] (A10.center) -- (A12.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=.2cm] {\scriptsize\bf G};
\draw [draw=none] (A11.center) -- (A12.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=.2cm] {\scriptsize\bf E};
\draw [draw=none] (A6.center) -- (A10.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.2cm] {\scriptsize\bf A};
\draw [draw=none] (A11.center) -- (A13.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=.2cm] {\scriptsize\bf B};
\draw [draw=none] (A13.center) -- (A16.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=-.16cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf B};
\draw [draw=none] (A16.center) -- (A21.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=-.16cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf E};
\draw [draw=none] (A21.center) -- (A23.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.20cm] {\scriptsize\bf G};
\draw [draw=none] (A23.center) -- (A25.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=.20cm] {\scriptsize\bf H};
\draw [draw=none] (A24.center) -- (A25.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=-.18cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf H};
\draw [draw=none] (A18.center) -- (A19.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=.18cm] {\scriptsize\bf C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am trying to imitate the following drawing.

[image]

But I`ve got stuck in completing the diagram; because there is always a third point present (as A5, A7, A8, A17, A22).

Drawing the remaining triangles override those points, creating another nodes overlapping them.

How can I solve this problem?

I tried many alternatives to start and rearrange the order of the nodes (including replacing some groups of triangles with hexagons), but I could not figure out how to do it without overlapping the nodes.

I`ve also tried to skip some inside triangles, but this leaves void (uncoloured) triangles, which is not acceptable when printing coloured models.

Comment: You could use the backgrounds tikzlibrary and put the tirangles on the background layer.  Or you could separate the triangle drawing and vertex labeling into two separate steps.  (The two are equivalent.)

Comment: @– 
John Kormylo Using background layer does not solve the problem. This still overlap the node.

Comment: @– 
John Kormylo I do not want to move the labels. I wand not to overlap the nodes. I think the problem is in the arrangement of nodes, but I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: Are you talking tikz nodes or something else?

Comment: @– 
John Kormylo I am talking about the nodes labelled A??

Answer (score 10):

While you are waiting for more Tikz-assistance, here is a version of your net in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), wrapped up in `luamplib`.  You need to compile this with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}

beginfig(1);
    numeric r; r = sqrt(3); 
    path N; 
    N = (0, -6) -- (r, -7) -- (r, -5) -- (r, -3) 
     -- (2r, -2) -- (3r, -1) -- (2r, 0) -- (r, 1) 
     -- (r, 3) -- (r, 5) -- (0, 6);
    N := N & N rotated 180 & cycle;
    N := N scaled 72;

    % draw N withpen pencircle scaled 2 withcolor 3/4;
    % for i=1 upto length N: dotlabel.bot(decimal i, point i of N); endfor
    
    draw for t=0, 2, 18, 6, 4, 14, 16, 8, 12, 10: point t of N -- endfor cycle;

    drawoptions(dashed evenly scaled 2);
    draw for t=19, 3, 17, 7, 13: point t of N -- endfor point 9 of N;
    draw point 3 of N -- point 7 of N;
    draw point 13 of N -- point 17 of N;
    drawoptions();

    vardef flap(expr p, a, r) =
        point 0 of p -- point a of p rotatedabout(point 0 of p, -r)
        -- point 1-a of p rotatedabout (point 1 of p, r) -- point 1 of p
    enddef;

    numeric i; i=0;
    forsuffixes t=H,H,F,f,h,D,c,C,d,h,G,G,a,A,g,E,B,b,e,g:
        picture P;
        if str t < "Z":
            P = thelabel(str t, 7 up);
            draw subpath(i, i+1) of N;
        else:
            P = thelabel(char (ASCII str t - 32), 7 down);
            draw subpath(i, i+1) of N dashed evenly scaled 2;
            draw flap(subpath(i, i+1) of N, 3/16, 28);
        fi
        draw P rotated angle direction i+1/2 of N
            shifted 1/2[point i of N, point incr i of N];
    endfor

    currentpicture := currentpicture rotated 30;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this when constructed:

[image]

For the mathematical details see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahemioctahedron.

### Notes on the code

- The path `N` defines the overall shape of the net, using normal coordinates and noting that if the length of each equilateral triangle is 2, then the altitude is `sqrt(3)`.
- To avoid repetition I defined the first half centred on the origin so I could complete the shape by connecting it to itself rotated.
- I've added extra points in the straight segments so that the path has length 20.
- I can then use the `point t of P` notation to draw all the internal lines, solid or dashed as needed.
- The loop at the end does the edge marks -- upper case for just a mark, lower case for a mark on a flap.
- There are no elegant ways of changing case in MP, but `char` and `ASCII` get the job done.
- The `incr i` idiom at the end steps round the path neatly.
- Finally the whole picture is rotated so it fits more neatly on a regular sheet of card when printed.

You can control the scaling of the whole diagram in a number of ways:

- you can change the size of the net by changing the line `N := N scaled 72` to whatever size you want.  72 here means 72 PostScript points = 1 inch = 2.54 cm.  So if you wanted is a bit smaller you could say `N := N scaled 2cm;`
- you can change the size of the whole completed drawing by adding something like `currentpicture := currentpicture scaled 0.5;` at the end
- you could scale the picture when you came to print it using whatever print options you get from whatever software you are using to view and print the PDF output.

If you want to learn more about Metapost in order to adapt this drawing to other nets, you can follow [this link](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) to find tutorials and reference manuals.  I don't know of any specific article on drawing nets, but there are plenty on drawing general geometric figures which could be adapted to this specific purpose.

### Update

A coloured version....

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
input colorbrewer-rgb
beginfig(1);
    numeric r; r = sqrt(3); 
    path N; 
    N = (0, -6) -- (r, -7) -- (r, -5) -- (r, -3) 
     -- (2r, -2) -- (3r, -1) -- (2r, 0) -- (r, 1) 
     -- (r, 3) -- (r, 5) -- (0, 6);
    N := N & N rotated 180 & cycle;
    N := N scaled 72;

    % draw N withpen pencircle scaled 2 withcolor 3/4;
    % for i=1 upto length N: dotlabel.bot(decimal i, point i of N); endfor
    path t; pair u, v;
    t = (origin -- 2 dir -30 -- 2 dir 30 -- cycle) scaled 72;
    u = point 1 of t - point 0 of t;
    v = point 2 of t - point 1 of t;
    vardef trig(expr i, j) = 
        t if not odd i: rotated 60 fi shifted (floor (i/2) * u) shifted (j * v) 
    enddef;
    
    drawoptions(withcolor 3/4[Accent 4 1, white]);
    fill trig( 1,  0);
    fill trig( 1, -3);
    fill trig( 2, -1);
    fill trig(-2,  2);
    fill trig(-2, -1);
    fill trig(-3,  0);
    drawoptions(withcolor 3/4[Accent 4 2, white]);
    fill trig( 1,  2);
    fill trig( 1, -1);
    fill trig( 2,  0);
    fill trig(-2,  1);
    fill trig(-2, -2);
    fill trig(-5, -1);
    drawoptions(withcolor 3/4[Accent 4 3, white]);
    fill trig( 1,  1);
    fill trig( 1, -2);
    fill trig(-3, -1);
    fill trig( 4,  0);
    fill trig(-2,  0);
    fill trig(-2, -3);
    drawoptions(withcolor 3/4[Accent 4 4, white]);
    fill trig( 0, 0);
    fill trig(-1, 1);
    fill trig( 0, 2);
    fill trig(-1,-1);
    fill trig( 0,-2);
    fill trig(-1,-3);

    drawoptions();
    draw for t=0, 2, 18, 6, 4, 14, 16, 8, 12, 10: point t of N -- endfor cycle;

    drawoptions(dashed evenly scaled 2);
    draw for t=19, 3, 17, 7, 13: point t of N -- endfor point 9 of N;
    draw point 3 of N -- point 7 of N;
    draw point 13 of N -- point 17 of N;
    drawoptions();

    vardef flap(expr p, a, r) =
        point 0 of p -- point a of p rotatedabout(point 0 of p, -r)
        -- point 1-a of p rotatedabout (point 1 of p, r) -- point 1 of p
    enddef;

    numeric i; i=0;
    forsuffixes t=H,H,F,f,h,D,c,C,d,h,G,G,a,A,g,E,B,b,e,g:
        picture P;
        if str t < "Z":
            P = thelabel(str t, 7 up);
            draw subpath(i, i+1) of N;
        else:
            P = thelabel(char (ASCII str t - 32), 8 down);
            draw subpath(i, i+1) of N dashed evenly scaled 2;
            draw flap(subpath(i, i+1) of N, 1/4, 28);
        fi
        draw P rotated angle direction i+1/2 of N
            shifted 1/2[point i of N, point incr i of N];
    endfor

    currentpicture := currentpicture rotated 30;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is now crying out to be made more generic, but that may take some time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I apply this code for other drawings using other types of polyhedra as squares, pentagons, hexagons,... etc.

Comment: How can I change the scaling of the whole drawing.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I will follow your link to try to learn about metapost.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an automated solution with TikZ.

We define a new macro called `\paperfold`. The call sequence is

```
\paperfold[fill=<color>, <options>]{<triangle sequence>}{<label sequence>}
```

The triangle sequence is a comma-separated list where each entry has the form `x/y/*/*/*`, where `x` is the horizontal position of the triangle and `y` is the vertical position. The `*` can either be empty (solid line) or `inward` (currently defined as a dashed line but could be easily changed).

So for example, `\paperfold[fill=red!30]{1/0/,2/0/,3/0/,2/1/}{}` (label sequence is empty) will create 4 triangles with solid lines: three in the bottom row (`y`=0) and one in the top row (`y`=1). Additional trailing `/` are optional. Note that triangles with `x+y` odd point upward and triangles with `x+y` even point downward. Choose your sequence accordingly.

[image]

Adding a label sequence:

```
\paperfold[fill=red!30]{1/0/,2/0/,3/0/,2/1/}%
    {A/1/0/tablabel/,C/1/0///tablabel,B/3/0//tablabel/,A/3/0/inlabel/,
    B/2/1//inlabel/,C/2/1///inlabel}
```

gives us a paper-folding model for a tetrahedron.

[image]

The label sequence has two kinds of labels `inlabel` and `tablabel` (labeled inside or on a tab). The label sequence is a comma-separated list where each entry has the form `<label>/x/y/*/*/*`. Each `*` is the label type or empty. The convention is that in any triangle the horizontal edge is first and subsequent edges are counterclockwise from there.

You can add many options to `\paperfold`. For example, the same triangle and label sequences above can produce the image

[image]

with the command

```
\paperfold[fill=yellow!30,draw=green!50!black,thick,rotate=60]{1/0/,2/0/,3/0/,2/1/}%
    {A/1/0/tablabel/,C/1/0///tablabel,B/3/0//tablabel/,A/3/0/inlabel/,
    B/2/1//inlabel/,C/2/1///inlabel}
```

Here is the code for an Octahemioctahedron:

```
\paperfold[fill=blue!30]{5/1//inward/inward,6/1/inward//inward,7/1/,8/1/,
    4/2/inward/inward/,5/2/,6/2/inward//inward,7/2///inward,
    0/3///inward,1/3/,2/3//inward/,3/3//inward/inward,4/3/inward//inward,5/3/,6/3/inward/inward/,7/3//inward/inward,
    1/4//inward/,2/4/inward/inward/,3/4/,4/4/inward//inward,5/4//inward/inward,6/4/inward/inward/,7/4/,8/4///inward,
    1/5//inward/inward,2/5/inward//inward,3/5/,4/5/inward//,
    0/6/,1/6/,2/6/inward//inward,3/6//inward/inward}%
    {E/5/1//tablabel/,G2/6/1/tablabel/,H2/8/1/inlabel/,H1/8/1//inlabel/,
    B/4/2//tablabel/,F/7/2//inlabel/,
    G1/0/3///tablabel,E/0/3/inlabel/,B/2/3/inlabel/,F/7/3///tablabel,
    A/1/4///inlabel,C/6/4/tablabel/,D/8/4/inlabel/,H1/8/4///tablabel,
    A/1/5//tablabel/,C/4/5//inlabel/,
    G2/0/6/inlabel/,G1/0/6//inlabel/,H2/2/6/tablabel/,D/3/6//tablabel/}
```

[image]

Note that to get dashed lines in the interior, *both* triangles adjacent to the dashed line must be given the `inward` key.

Here is the complete code, including the examples above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{inward/.style={dashed}}
\tikzset{
    tablabel/.style={
        decoration={
            show path construction,
            lineto code={
                \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst); \pgfgetlastxy{\a}{\b};
                \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast); \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y};
                \coordinate (uu) at ($(0,0)!2mm!(\b-\y,\x-\a)$);
                \coordinate (uv) at ($(0,0)!4mm!(\x-\a,\y-\b)$);
                \draw(\a,\b)--($(\a,\b)-(uu)+(uv)$) to node[above=-.9mm,sloped,allow upside down]{\tiny \textsf{#1}} ($(\x,\y)-(uu)-(uv)$)--(\x,\y);
            }
        }, decorate
    } 
}
\tikzset{
    inlabel/.style={
        decoration={
            show path construction,
            lineto code={
                \path(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) to node[above=-.9mm,sloped,allow upside down]{\tiny \textsf{#1}} (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            }
        }, decorate
    } 
}

\newcommand{\paperfold}[3][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, #1]
    \foreach \x/\y/\sa/\sb/\sc in {#2} {
        \begin{scope}[yscale=sqrt(3),rotate around={180*(\x+\y+1):(\x,\y+.5)}]
            \fill (\x-1,\y)--(\x+1,\y)--(\x,\y+1)--cycle;
            \draw[\sa](\x-1,\y)--(\x+1,\y);
            \draw[\sb](\x+1,\y)--(\x,\y+1);
            \draw[\sc](\x,\y+1)--(\x-1,\y);
        \end{scope}
    }
    \foreach \z/\x/\y/\ta/\tb/\tc in {#3} {
        \begin{scope}[yscale=sqrt(3),rotate around={180*(\x+\y+1):(\x,\y+.5)}]
            \path[\ta=\z](\x-1,\y)--(\x+1,\y);
            \path[\tb=\z](\x+1,\y)--(\x,\y+1);
            \path[\tc=\z](\x,\y+1)--(\x-1,\y);
        \end{scope}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}}


\begin{document}

\paperfold[fill=red!30]{1/0/,2/0/,3/0/,2/1/}{}

\paperfold[fill=red!30]{1/0/,2/0/,3/0/,2/1/}%
    {A/1/0/tablabel/,C/1/0///tablabel,B/3/0//tablabel/,A/3/0/inlabel/,B/2/1//inlabel/,C/2/1///inlabel}

\paperfold[fill=yellow!30,draw=green!50!black,thick,rotate=60]{1/0/,2/0/,3/0/,2/1/}%
    {A/1/0/tablabel/,C/1/0///tablabel,B/3/0//tablabel/,A/3/0/inlabel/,B/2/1//inlabel/,C/2/1///inlabel}

\paperfold[fill=blue!30]{5/1//inward/inward,6/1/inward//inward,7/1/,8/1/,
    4/2/inward/inward/,5/2/,6/2/inward//inward,7/2///inward,
    0/3///inward,1/3/,2/3//inward/,3/3//inward/inward,4/3/inward//inward,5/3/,6/3/inward/inward/,7/3//inward/inward,
    1/4//inward/,2/4/inward/inward/,3/4/,4/4/inward//inward,5/4//inward/inward,6/4/inward/inward/,7/4/,8/4///inward,
    1/5//inward/inward,2/5/inward//inward,3/5/,4/5/inward//,
    0/6/,1/6/,2/6/inward//inward,3/6//inward/inward}%
    {E/5/1//tablabel/,J/6/1/tablabel/,K/8/1/inlabel/,H/8/1//inlabel/,
    B/4/2//tablabel/,F/7/2//inlabel/,
    G/0/3///tablabel,E/0/3/inlabel/,B/2/3/inlabel/,F/7/3///tablabel,
    A/1/4///inlabel,C/6/4/tablabel/,D/8/4/inlabel/,H/8/4///tablabel,
    A/1/5//tablabel/,C/4/5//inlabel/,
    J/0/6/inlabel/,G/0/6//inlabel/,K/2/6/tablabel/,D/3/6//tablabel/}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I will study it. The labels are correct. The letters indicate the sequence of gluing. Using 4 Gs means that these are glued at the same time. How can I apply your code for other polyhedra as pentagon, hexagon, octagon,... etc.

Comment: I understand now about the labels. I changed them to G1/G2 and H1/H2. Using different polygons would require significant revision, but if you have something specific in mind I may be able to help.

Comment: @– 
Sandy G Thank you very much for your concern. I draw many polyhedra models. For example https://i.stack.imgur.com/geSDf.png So I need a flexible code to be applied in all possible situations.

Comment: @Hany: You might consider posting a new question to address more general situations.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to thank Thruston and Sandy G for their excellent answers using Metapost and paperfold macro. I appreciate very much their effort, concern and time.

But I need an answer which can be applied when I use this code for drawing other polyhedra; and those answers are specific for the current situation only.

So, I figured out how to go around my problem, by leaving empty areas which could be manually filled; as in the following code.
I filled those empty areas with different colour just to demonstrate my point.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=10mm, right=10mm, top=10mm, bottom=10mm}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false,colorlinks,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue, plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,breaklinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{folding,calc,calendar,decorations,arrows,automata,positioning,mindmap,backgrounds}
\newif\iffill
\fillfalse
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
patron/.style={%
 line join=round, rounded corners=.05pt, draw, thin},
patron side/.style={patron},
patron languette/.style={patron},%
}
\newcounter{NodePat}
\NewDocumentCommand{\PolygReg}{%
O{3}%
O{}
m%
O{A}%
}
{%
\ifx\relax#2\relax
  \iffill
    \ifnum#1=3 \def\tmp{fill=blue!25!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=4 \def\tmp{fill=blue!30!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=5 \def\tmp{fill=blue!35!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=6 \def\tmp{fill=blue!40!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=7 \def\tmp{fill=blue!45!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=8 \def\tmp{fill=blue!50!white}\else
    \def\tmp{}\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \else
    \def\tmp{}
  \fi 
\else
  \def\tmp{#2}
\fi
\foreach \a/\b in {#3} 
{%
\expandafter\path\expandafter[\tmp, patron side] let
\p1 = ($(\a)!.5!(\b)$) ,
\n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} ,
\p2 = ($(\p1)!1/tan(180/#1)!90:(\b)$)
in
(\a)--(\b)
\foreach \i [%
  evaluate=\i as \j using (\i-1)*360/#1] in {3,...,#1} {%
  -- ($(\p2)!1!\j:(\a)$) coordinate (#4\theNodePat)
  \pgfextra{\stepcounter{NodePat}}
  }
-- cycle ;
}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Languette}{%
O{.15}  %
D<>{24} %
m       %
D<>{24} %
O{A}
}%
{%
\foreach \b/\a in {#3} {%
\path[patron languette, fill=yellow] let
\p1 = ($(#5\b)!#1/sin(#2)!-#2:(#5\a)$),
\p2 = ($(#5\a)!#1/sin(#4)!#4:(#5\b)$)
in
(#5\a) -- (#5\b) -- (\p1) -- (\p2) -- cycle ; }
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AffNodesPatron}[1][A]{%
 \newcount\X
 \X=1
 \loop
 \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@pi@A\the\X\endcsname\pgfpictureid
 \node[font={\footnotesize},red] at (A\the\X) {A\the\X} ;
 \advance \X by 1
 \else
 \X=0
 \fi
 \unless\ifnum \X=0
 \repeat
}
\makeatother

Octahemioctahedron

\fillfalse
\hskip -1.2cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3.8, rotate=0]
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (A2) at (0,-1) ;
\setcounter{NodePat}{3}
\PolygReg[3][fill=blue!20!white]{A1/A2,A3/A2,A3/A4,A4/A2,A4/A6,A4/A7}
\PolygReg[3][fill=blue!20!white]{A7/A6,A9/A6,A9/A10,A11/A10}
\PolygReg[3][fill=blue!20!white]{A9/A11,A9/A13}
\PolygReg[3][fill=blue!20!white]{A14/A13,A15/A13,A14/A15,A14/A17,A18/A17,A19/A17}
\PolygReg[3][fill=blue!20!white]{A15/A16,A21/A16,A15/A21}
\PolygReg[3][fill=blue!20!white]{A21/A22,A21/A24,A25/A24,A19/A20}
\Languette{5/3,8/5,2/6,10/12,19/18,13/16,16/22,23/20,22/24,20/27}
\AffNodesPatron

\draw [draw=none,fill=blue!15!white] (A5.center) -- (A4.center) -- (A8.center);
\draw [draw=none,fill=blue!15!white] (A8.center) -- (A9.center) -- (A14.center) -- (A18.center);
\draw [draw=none,fill=blue!15!white] (A21.center) -- (A23.center) -- (A25.center);
\draw [draw=none,fill=blue!15!white] (A15.center) -- (A17.center) -- (A20.center) -- (A23.center);

\draw [thick, white, dashed] (A3.center) -- (A5.center) (A5.center) -- (A6.center) (A2.center) -- (A13.center) (A6.center) -- (A7.center) (A10.center) -- (A12.center) (A18.center) -- (A17.center) (A18.center) -- (A19.center) (A18.center) -- (A13.center) (A13.center) -- (A23.center) (A13.center) -- (A22.center) (A22.center) -- (A24.center) (A22.center) -- (A27.center) (A5.center) -- (A8.center);

\draw [thick, black, dashed] (A17.center) -- (A23.center) (A7.center) -- (A18.center);

\draw [thick, black] (A23.center) -- (A25.center) (A8.center) -- (A18.center) (A14.center) -- (A7.center) ;

\draw [draw=none] (A2.center) -- (A6.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=-.18cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf A};
\draw [draw=none] (A6.center) -- (A10.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.2cm] {\scriptsize\bf A};
\draw [draw=none] (A11.center) -- (A13.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=.2cm] {\scriptsize\bf B};
\draw [draw=none] (A13.center) -- (A16.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=-.16cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf B};
\draw [draw=none] (A18.center) -- (A19.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=.18cm] {\scriptsize\bf C};
\draw [draw=none] (A18.center) -- (A8.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=-.18cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf C};
\draw [draw=none] (A27.center) -- (A19.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.18cm] {\scriptsize\bf D};
\draw [draw=none] (A5.center) -- (A8.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=.18cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf D};
\draw [draw=none] (A11.center) -- (A12.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=.2cm] {\scriptsize\bf E};
\draw [draw=none] (A16.center) -- (A22.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=-.16cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf E};
\draw [draw=none] (A1.center) -- (A2.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=.15cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf G};
\draw [draw=none] (A20.center) -- (A23.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.2cm] {\scriptsize\bf F};
\draw [draw=none] (A25.center) -- (A23.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=-.18cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf F};
\draw [draw=none] (A1.center) -- (A3.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.2cm] {\scriptsize\bf G};
\draw [draw=none] (A10.center) -- (A12.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=.2cm] {\scriptsize\bf G};
\draw [draw=none] (A22.center) -- (A24.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.20cm] {\scriptsize\bf G};
\draw [draw=none] (A3.center) -- (A5.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=.18cm] {\scriptsize\bf H};
\draw [draw=none] (A24.center) -- (A26.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=.20cm] {\scriptsize\bf H};
\draw [draw=none] (A25.center) -- (A26.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=-.18cm,yshift=0cm] {\scriptsize\bf H};
\draw [draw=none] (A20.center) -- (A27.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=0cm,yshift=-.2cm] {\scriptsize\bf H};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]