# Modifying a paper-folding-diagram code to draw other polygons

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612523/modifying-a-paper-folding-diagram-code) can be used to draw any coloured regular polygon with any number of sides.
It draws equilateral triangles.

Is it possible to modify this code to draw also isosceles triangles (with controllable length of the sides) as in the following diagrams!

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lwdthc}{.2mm}
\newif\iffill
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
patron/.style={%
 line join=round, rounded corners=.05pt, draw, line width=\lwdthc},
patron side/.style={patron},
patron languette/.style={patron},%
}
\newcounter{NodePat}
\NewDocumentCommand{\PolygReg}{%
O{3}%
O{}
m%
O{A}%
}
{%
\ifx\relax#2\relax
  \iffill
    \ifnum#1=3 \def\tmp{fill=blue!25!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=4 \def\tmp{fill=blue!28!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=5 \def\tmp{fill=blue!31!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=6 \def\tmp{fill=blue!34!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=7 \def\tmp{fill=blue!37!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=8 \def\tmp{fill=blue!40!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=9 \def\tmp{fill=blue!43!white}\else
    \ifnum#1=10 \def\tmp{fill=blue!46!white}\else
    \def\tmp{}\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \else
    \def\tmp{}%
  \fi 
\else
  \def\tmp{#2}%
\fi
\foreach \a/\b in {#3} 
{%
\expandafter\path\expandafter[\tmp, patron side] let%
\p1 = ($(\a)!.5!(\b)$) ,
\n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} ,
\p2 = ($(\p1)!1/tan(180/#1)!90:(\b)$)
in
(\a)--(\b)
\foreach \i [%
  evaluate=\i as \j using (\i-1)*360/#1] in {3,...,#1} {%
  -- ($(\p2)!1!\j:(\a)$) coordinate (#4\theNodePat)
  \pgfextra{\stepcounter{NodePat}}
  }
-- cycle ;
}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Languette}{%
O{.15}  %
D<>{24} %
m       %
D<>{24} %
O{A}
}%do not leave an empty line after it
{%
\foreach \b/\a in {#3} {%
\path[patron languette, fill=yellow] let
\p1 = ($(#5\b)!#1/sin(#2)!-#2:(#5\a)$),
\p2 = ($(#5\a)!#1/sin(#4)!#4:(#5\b)$)
in
(#5\a) -- (#5\b) -- (\p1) -- (\p2) -- cycle ; }
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AffNodesPatron}[1][A]{%
 \newcount\X
 \X=1
 \loop
 \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@pi@A\the\X\endcsname\pgfpictureid
 \node[font={\footnotesize},red] at (A\the\X) {A\the\X} ;
 \advance \X by 1
 \else
 \X=0
 \fi
 \unless\ifnum \X=0
 \repeat
}
\makeatother
\filltrue
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (A2) at (0,-1) ;
\setcounter{NodePat}{3}
\PolygReg[3]{A1/A2}
\PolygReg[4]{A3/A2}
\PolygReg[5]{A3/A5}
\PolygReg[6]{A7/A6}
\Languette{3/1}
\AffNodesPatron
\draw [draw=none] (A1.center) -- (A3.center) node [purple, pos=.5, xshift=.4cm,yshift=0cm] {\bf B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]